# Existe como criar um certificado valido para localhost Apache?

Tags: apache, ssl, certificado-digital, https, localhost

Veja só no meu desenvolvimento local tenho feito uso de https://localhost, criei o certificado pelo openssl do apache, funciona beleza.

Acontece que como não é um certificado que esta em uma fonte externa o navegador diz que não é seguro e coloca aquela pagina de confirmação.

No firefox podemos adicionar o certificado e ele não pergunta mais, mas no chrome que ultimamente esta adotando políticas chatas não deixa você adicionar um certificado á lista (procurei e não encontrei), então toda vez que você fecha e abre ele mostra essa bendita pagina.

Tem como criar um certificado valido pra usar em localhost em todos os meus Virtuais Hosts para desenvolvimento?

Lendo na internet vi que existe o **letsencrypt.org** que gera certificados gratuitos, porém os programas usados são em vários sistemas, menos no Windows, no servidor CentOS eu consegui habilitar os certificados, mas como minha maquina de desenvolvimento é Windows eu precisava que fosse para este sistema operacional.

Nota: Não gostaria de usar maquinas virtuais, consomem um bom recurso da maquina.

Answer (score 1):

Por desenho localhost não é um dominio reconhecido fora de um PC e portanto não é permitido, pelas autoridades emissoras de certificados publicas (CA's - como a letsencrypt.org) gerar certificados reconhecido publicamente para este domínio.

Dito isto, nada impede a criação de uma CA só sua. E com ela assinar um certificato emitido por si, para o dominio localhost. Este certificado será reconhecido só onde a sua CA for reconhecida como sendo de confiança.... este é o principio da cadeia de confiança SSL/TLS. "Só confiamos nos certificados assinados porque alguém em quem confiamos".

Para isso só é necessário criar uma CA. Basicamente um certificato assinado por ele próprio (Self-Signed Certificate - Ver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl) e depois emitir um certificado para o dominio localhost e assinalo com o certificado referido anteriormente (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-a-certificate-signing-request-with-your-certification-authority).

Na posse destes dois certificados, usa-se o certificado localhost, depois de assinado na configuração do servidor Apache e importa-se a componente publica (não a chave!!!!) do certificado assinado por ele proprio, nos browsers para que o certificados assinados por este sejam reconhecidos e se tenha uma cadeia de confiança.

No chrome também é possível adicionar certificados (a não ser que as permissões não o permitam)- Seguir https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206081828-How-to-manually-install-the-Securly-SSL-certificate-in-Chrome